# BOTTOM NAVIGATION VIEW HIDES

Tags: android, fragment, bottomnavigationview

I have a problem with my app. I have a bottom navigation view with 3 different fragments, although currently only the main this with things. The problem comes when I try to move from one of the two fragments of the left to the main, that is when the bottom navigation view is hidden. I attached the main code.

PD: I have all the libraries in 25.3.1 version (if useful).

Thank you for your attention.

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/containerr"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#0f6b96"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/color_state_light"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/color_state_light"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation_basic">

</android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transation = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transation.replace(R.id.container, new Home()).commit();


}
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener onNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transation = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.home:
                transation.replace(R.id.container, new Home()).commit();
                return true;

            case R.id.ofertas:
                transation.replace(R.id.container, new Ofertas()).commit();
                return true;

            case R.id.contacto:
                transation.replace(R.id.container, new Contacto()).commit();
                return true;

        }


        return false;
    }
};
```

I add you two images too.

[Ofertas Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Ofw.png)

[Home Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YOQ9.png)

Comment: i suggest you to combine nav bottom view with viewpager

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in `fitSystemWindow == true` , i had similar issue ,  after deleting it the problem has gone.